# How to merge log files and sort by time

Tags: shell, logging

I have many log files, like that

**log file 1**

```
2016-09-11_19:40:15.537#15437 [INFO] A1
2016-09-11_19:40:15.537#15437 [WARN] A2
2016-09-11_19:40:15.542#15437 [INFO] A3
```

**log file 2**

```
2016-09-11_19:40:15.537#437 [INFO] B1
2016-09-11_19:40:15.540#437 [INFO] B2
```

I wish I can merge them by script or other method like that 
**sort by time**

```
2016-09-11_19:40:15.537#15437 [INFO] A1
2016-09-11_19:40:15.537#15437 [WARN] A2
2016-09-11_19:40:15.537#437 [INFO] B1
2016-09-11_19:40:15.540#437 [INFO] B2
2016-09-11_19:40:15.542#15437 [INFO] A3
```

How do I to merge the files with efficient way ?
thanks !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ref: [Merging multiple log files by date including multilines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866772/merging-multiple-log-files-by-date-including-multilines)

As mentioned in the above question, if you are certain that all the log lines start with timestamp, you can do:

```
cat logA.log logB.log | sort -n
```

This would not work when there are other lines such as stack trace which do not start with timestamp.
I think you can check out the above question and answers if your considering a similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try rust-based tool [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 --color=never /var/log > logs-merged.log
```

*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher* will sort varying log messages by datetime.

Answer (score -1):

Insert all of your files to an empty **Notepad++** document.

Edit → Line Operations → Sort Lines Lexicographically Ascending.